# Do I have to link to the glyphicon website?

Tags: internet, software, licensing, open-source-software

The [Bootstrap homepage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons) states :

> Glyphicons Halflings are normally not available for free, but their creator has made them available for Bootstrap free of cost. As a thank you, we only ask that you include a link back to Glyphicons whenever possible.

- it asks me to "link back to Glyphicons" - is this legally binding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their license is [here](https://www.glyphicons.com/license/), and it says explicitly

> You do not have to indicate the name of the author or giving any
>   credits to GLYPHICONS.com, although it is always appreciated.

It is a suggestion and polite request, not a legal requirement.